# Parse HEX file Parrallel with Filestream

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, filestream

So i'm trying to speed up a `For i as integer` to get max preformace. I'm using more and more Parrallel and Async method in my code and it helps me alot. However currently i'm stuck with this one. I simply what to loop trhough a file an reading specific index position to see what's in the file so i can do certain things with it later on.

This is an example of the current For:

```
Using fs As New FileStream(PathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)    
     For i As Long = 0 To fs.Length Step 1024

          'Go to the calculated index in the file
          fs.Seek(i, SeekOrigin.Begin)

          'Now get 24 bytes at the current index
          fs.Read(buffer, 0, 24)

          'Do some stuff with it
          List.Add(Buffer)
      Next
End Using
```

The files can be 15MB to 4GB in size. Currently i'm stuck at how to use a Step 1024 in a `Parrallel.For` and also how to approach it thread-safe. Hopefully someone could help me out with this.

Comment: The FileStream members are not thread safe so you cant use them in a parallel loop.

Comment: But what about the optional parameters UseAsync in the New method?

Comment: Async and parallel is not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm aware of that. Maybe i wasn't clear in my first post but i'm looking for another/faster way to loop through a file with x Steps.

Comment: To be honest, I suspect that if you're reading the file from a hard disk, unless each `do stuff` takes a fairly substanial amount of time, you may find that even multi-threading the process, won't be much quicker. Your bottleneck is probably going to be your hard disk, not your software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be marked down, but if memory usage isn't a huge problem, then I would suggest reading the whole file and storing just those 24 byte sequences in an array of byte(23). Then using `Parallel.For` processing the array. On my pc the array takes up about 160mb for a 4gb. The speed of reading will of course depend on the system used. On my PC it take around 25 seconds.

Try this..

```
Imports System.Math
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    'create the data array, with just 1 element to start with
    'so that it can be resized then you know how many 1024 byte
    'chunks you have in your file
    Dim DataArray(1)() As Byte


    Private Sub ReadByteSequences(pathtoFile As String)
        Using fs As New FileStream(pathtoFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            'resize the array when you have the file size
            ReDim DataArray(CInt(Math.Floor(fs.Length) / 1024))
            For i As Long = 0 To fs.Length Step 1024
                Dim buffer(23) As Byte
                fs.Seek(i, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, 24)
                'store each 24 byte sequence in order in the 
                'DataArray for later processing
                DataArray(CInt(Math.Floor(i / 1024))) = buffer
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessDataArray()
        Parallel.For(0, DataArray.Length, Sub(i As Integer)
                                              'do atuff in parallel
                                          End Sub)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your example. Tried it and gain some speed will implement it further down my code. Thanks!